# Finding the value of $f_{x+y}$ for multivariate normal distributon

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that bivariate normal distribution is

[image]

I need to find the value of $f_{X+Y}$ and the variable are standard normal.

If the variables are standard normal,

$$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,\mathrm dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,\mathrm dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12 x^2\right)\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12(z-x)^2\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
= \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac12\left(x^2+(z-x)^2\right)\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
= \frac1{2\pi}\exp(-1/2z^2) \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(zx)\,\mathrm dx$$

I get stuck after this because the integral turns out to be zero.

Need some guidance to solve this question.

Comment: You missed $x^2$ in exponent. Also I don't understand how did you remove minus sign there.

Comment: i didn't miss the $x^2$ in exponent...

Comment: Do you bielive that $-\frac12\left(x^2 + (z-x)^2\right) = -\frac12 z^2 + zx$? Surely I know one such $x$...

Comment: @Smylic This looks hideous. Please use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` instead, if you insist on improving the formatting.

Comment: @Smylic made a careless mistake.... sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A painless approach is to understand what the parameters of the density of the bivariate normal $(X,Y)$ mean.

One sees that $X=\mu_X+\sigma_XU$ and $Y=\mu_Y+\sigma_YV$ where $U$ and $V$ are standard normal, and that $\rho=\mathrm{Corr}(X,Y)=\mathrm{Cov}(U,V)$. Hence, 
$$
V=\rho U+\tau W,\qquad\tau=\sqrt{1-\rho^2},
$$ 
where $(U,W)$ is i.i.d. standard normal.
Thus, $X+Y=\mu_X+\mu_Y+Z$ where 
$$
Z=\sigma_XU+\sigma_YV=(\sigma_X+\rho\sigma_Y)U+\sigma_Y\tau W
$$ 
is centered normal with variance
$$
E[Z^2]=(\sigma_X+\rho\sigma_Y)^2+\sigma_Y^2\tau^2.
$$
Finally, $X+Y$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, where
$$
\mu=\mu_X+\mu_Y,\qquad\sigma^2=\sigma_X^2+2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y+\sigma_Y^2.
$$

Comment: any idea where my mistake is in my solution?

Comment: Sure: to go from the first integral to the second one, you replace $f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)$ by $f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$. This is not kosher since $f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)$ is not $f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$, as the formula for $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ at the beginning of your post shows.